# grow up logical block size: - FAILED: failed to dump sfdisk info for /dev/sdb

Tags: linux, ubuntu, diskspace, lvm

How can I grow up space of the `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`?

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              298M  1.2M  297M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   78G   63G   13G  84% /
tmpfs                              1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          974M  307M  600M  34% /boot
/dev/loop1                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2751
/dev/loop0                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2785
/dev/loop2                          64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1950
/dev/loop3                          64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1974
/dev/loop4                          92M   92M     0 100% /snap/lxd/23991
/dev/loop5                          92M   92M     0 100% /snap/lxd/24061
/dev/loop6                          54M   54M     0 100% /snap/snapd/19457
/dev/loop7                          54M   54M     0 100% /snap/snapd/19361
tmpfs                              298M     0  298M   0% /run/user/1002
```

information about all available devices:

```
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0                         2:0    1    4K  0 disk 
loop0                       7:0    0 55.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/2785
loop1                       7:1    0 55.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/2751
loop2                       7:2    0 63.5M  1 loop /snap/core20/1950
loop3                       7:3    0 63.5M  1 loop /snap/core20/1974
loop4                       7:4    0 91.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/23991
loop5                       7:5    0 91.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24061
loop6                       7:6    0 53.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19457
loop7                       7:7    0 53.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19361
sda                         8:0    0   30G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part 
├─sda2                      8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0   29G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   79G  0 lvm  /
sdb                         8:16   0  120G  0 disk 
└─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   253:0    0   79G  0 lvm  /
sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

```
$ sudo growpart /dev/sdb 1
WARN: unknown label 
failed [sfd_dump:1] sfdisk --unit=S --dump /dev/sdb
sfdisk: /dev/sdb: does not contain a recognized partition table
FAILED: failed to dump sfdisk info for /dev/sdb
```

Answer (score 0):

the attributes of a logical volume before resizing

```
$ sudo lvdisplay
--- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv    ️
  LV Name                ubuntu-lv
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                5w3Tyc-6NUd-R5yk-3gj5-aPWq-73Qa-DAB0Mz
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu-server, 2021-09-24 13:15:35 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                78.99 GiB                   ️
  Current LE             20222
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
    Block device           253:0
```

extend the size of a logical volume

```
$ sudo lvextend -L+30g /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
Size of logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv changed from 88.99 GiB (22782 extents) to 118.99 GiB (30462 extents).
Logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv successfully resized.
```

size of logical volume was changed

```
$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0                         2:0    1    4K  0 disk
loop0                       7:0    0 55.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/2785
loop1                       7:1    0 55.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/2751
loop2                       7:2    0 63.5M  1 loop /snap/core20/1950
loop3                       7:3    0 63.5M  1 loop /snap/core20/1974
loop4                       7:4    0 91.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/23991
loop5                       7:5    0 91.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24061
loop6                       7:6    0 53.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19457
loop7                       7:7    0 53.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19361
sda                         8:0    0   30G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part
├─sda2                      8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0   29G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  119G  0 lvm  /    ️
sdb                         8:16   0  120G  0 disk      ️
└─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   253:0    0  119G  0 lvm  /    ️
sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

resize the file systems

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Filesystem at /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 12, new_desc_blocks = 15
The filesystem on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv is now 31193088 (4k) blocks long.
```

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              298M  1.2M  297M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  117G   66G   47G  59% /    ️
tmpfs                              1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          974M  307M  600M  34% /boot
/dev/loop1                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2751
/dev/loop0                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2785
/dev/loop2                          64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1950
/dev/loop3                          64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1974
/dev/loop4                          92M   92M     0 100% /snap/lxd/23991
/dev/loop5                          92M   92M     0 100% /snap/lxd/24061
/dev/loop6                          54M   54M     0 100% /snap/snapd/19457
/dev/loop7                          54M   54M     0 100% /snap/snapd/19361
tmpfs                              298M     0  298M   0% /run/user/1002
```